# Перенос вызова конструктора на следующую строку

Tags: python, code-style, pep8, white-space

Создаю 1 statement-ом класс `X` и его инстанс `x`, однако строка длинная, поэтому переношу с помощью `\`:

```
x = create_class('X', 'int_field') \
    (int_field=42)
```

Но мне пишет:

> PEP 8: E211 whitespace before '('

Никакого whitespace кроме переноса строки на 1-ой строке после `\` нет. Как тогда стилистически правильно надо переносить, чтобы не было никаких предупреждений?

Comment: Но там же явно отступ/табуляция в начале второй строки

Comment: Как подскажет хорошая IDE. ;)

Comment: @CrazyElf обратного я не писал, если это не top-level scope, то там должны быть отступы в любом случае, так что их удаление не решает проблему

Comment: @VictorVosMottor это результат после форматирования PyCharm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так:

```
x = create_class('X', 'int_field')(
    int_field=42
)
```

А использовать `\` для переноса строки вообще крайне не рекомендуется. Если после него случайно поставить пробел, то можно получить багу, отлавливать которую придётся долго и мучительно.

Comment: А как переносить математические выражения без использования \ ? Например, `f = x + y + ... перенос + z`. Лишние пробелы в конце строк обычно удаляются IDE

Comment: Нашёл [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53200), кому интересно

Comment: Если вы работает над вашим кодом в одиночку и уверены, что ваше IDE удалит неожиданные пробелы, то не буду вас отговаривать )) Но если работаете над кодом в команде, то нельзя быть уверенным, у кого какая IDE, и лучше косую черту для переноса не использовать.

Answer (score 0):

В соответствии с [этим ответом](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53200), буду использовать дополнительные скобки вместо `\`:

```
x = (create_class('X', 'int_field')
     (int_field=42))

f = (x
     + y
     - z)
```

Comment: Выглядит странно :) я бы закрывающую скобку перенес на новую строку и не стал бы превращать питон в лисп :)

Comment: 1 - это в целом довольно странный код. Лучше или на одной строке оставлять, или разбить на 2 выражения, так будет намного лучше читаться. 2 - вроде бы обычно операторы наоборот на предыдущей строке оставляют при переносе арифметических выражений